# update database each year using cron job

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update mysql database using **cron job** in php project. Below is the piece of code that I want to run each year. I have tried using events scheduler in mysql but I failed.

```
$stud="select * from student_class where class<4";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($stud))
 {
  $sql = "INSERT into student class(id,student_id,class,year) values('','{$row  
 ['student_id']}','{$row['class']}','{$row['year']}+1')" ;
  mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Use this [documentation](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) to help you adding cron jobs on your server

```
crontab -e
1 2 3 4 5 php /path/to/php_file arg1 arg2
```

Where :

```
1: Minute (0-59)
2: Hours (0-23)
3: Day (0-31)
4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
/path/to/php_file- Script or command name to schedule
```

So your cron job would look like this to execute at 00:00 on January 1 of each year:

```
0 0 1 1 * php /path/to/php_file arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have php-cli installed so you can run scripts from your terminal. In your script the location of the php binary should be in the header, eg #/usr/bin/php
Get the script working in the terminal environment.

Then edit the crontab as Philippe suggests.